# Fortran and C Mixed Programming (Shared Memory)

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have an existing Fortran codebase I'm working with and it's quite large.  I am no Fortran programmer so I know that I'm not doing everything correctly here.

I'm trying to create and initialize an array of 1.6 million integers.  I cannot get this to initialize in Fortran (using ifort or gfort) as I either would have too many line continuations or too long of lines.

So naturally, I switched to C and wrote a function to just initialize an array and it compiles in seconds with no problem.  Now I'm trying to link the two together properly.  I created a small test case here to simplify things.  Here are the three files I'm working with:

init.c

```
void c_init_()
{
  static const int f_init_g[1600000] =
  {
    3263, 322, 3261, 60, 32249, 32244, 3229, 23408, 252407, 25326,
    25805, 25723, 25562, 25787, 4549, 32248, 32244, 32243, 253207, 21806,
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    25805, 25723, 25562, 25787, 4549, 32248, 32244, 32243, 253207, 21806
  };
}
```

init_mod.f90

```
MODULE INIT_MOD

  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
  IMPLICIT NONE
  SAVE

  TYPE :: INIT_TYPE
    INTEGER (C_INT), DIMENSION(1600000) :: INIT
  END TYPE INIT_TYPE
  TYPE (C_PTR), BIND(C,NAME="f_init_g") :: INIT_CP
  TYPE (INIT_TYPE), POINTER :: INIT_FP

END MODULE INIT_MOD
```

main.f90

```
  PROGRAM INIT

    USE INIT_MOD
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

    TYPE (INIT_TYPE) :: INIT_T
    CALL c_init()
    CALL C_F_POINTER(INIT_CP,INIT_FP)
    INIT_T = INIT_FP

  END PROGRAM INIT
```

I compile this using the following commands:

```
icc -c init.c
ifort -c init_mod.f90
ifort main.f90 init_mod.o init.o
```

I get a segmentation fault when running because `INIT_CP` points to nothing as far as I can tell.  I know I'm not successfully getting `INIT_CP` to point at the array in my C function.  So I'm trying to figure out how to do that.

I would like if someone has a suggestion on how to initialize this array natively in Fortran.  My final option that I'll do is make a small initialization of this array in assembly and write a script to generate the assembly code to initialize this array myself (based off the assembly from the small initialization I can mimic the same thing for any size array).  I'm not as excited to do that, but it may be the easiest and most reliable solution.

Most importantly I want other Fortran subroutines that use this array to see that it is static in shape and value so that appropriate inter procedural optimizations can be done.

Comment: Is the mismatch in array length (1600000 vs. 1605320) intentional?

Comment: Not at all.  Just fixed that thank you.

Comment: Does that resolve the segmentation violation?

Comment: Are you really writing a source code file with 1605320 data values to initialise the array ?  That's crazeee !   Put the numbers in a file and read them on program startup.

Comment: No, my arrays are the same size in my source code.  This was just a miscopy into this post

Comment: I agree with @HighPerformanceMark (and there have been related questions from memory), but using (lots and lots and lots) of `data` statements wouldn't require long lines or many continuations.

Comment: C programmer, not Fortran: ```f_init_g``` is being declared on the stack of ```c_init_()```, albeit ```static```, this looks suspect. How is ```f_init_g``` supposed to be made visible to the Fortran namespace? In the C module it's hidden in the function and so wouldn't have any visibility in the compilation unit.  Short story, try making ```f_init_g``` a global static variable instead of a function static variable?

Comment: @Erik `static` variables do not land on the stack. Please learn some basic C, `static` variables with function scope are a very elementary feature.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I'd like to give the compiler every chance to know everything about this array for optimizations.  I'd also like to do this with a number of arrays similar in size and don't want to use runtime I/O.  I'd rather this be known before runtime.

Comment: @FUZxxl depends on how old your compiler is I suppose.

Comment: @Erik I agree. If your compiler is from before 1975 it might not support this feature.

Comment: I can understand why you want the array to be static (save), but do you have to initialize it at compile time? Can't you just generate executable initialization subroutine with `f_init_g(1)=3263` and so on? Even more, by using a pointer I am quite woried you are actually loosing all those benefits of the static array and the Fortran compiler will have to be worried about aliasing!

Comment: @VladimirF  Maybe I did something wrong, but I wrote a subroutine that assigned values to the array 10 at a time 160k times, and it spent forever compiling until the compiler failed.

Comment: @francescalus Are you saying something along the lines of: data init(1)/x/, init(2)/y/, init(3)/z/  ?  I know this is done at runtime, but I guess that's not terrible.  I'd rather, again, to get this at compile time, but this is worth a try.

Comment: Using a `data` statement (and yours could be simplified as `data init(1:3)/x,y,z/`) provides explicit initialization, just as `int :: init(3)=[x,y,z]`.  This may well be a compile-time thing.  [It may be that you aren't using "initialize" in the strict Fortran sense of the word, but `data` and `=` on a declaration are initialization, `init(1:3) = [x,y,z]` outside the declaration is assignment which isn't initialization.]

Comment: @francescalus I had just read this: The data statement is performed only once, right before the execution of the program starts. For this reason, the data statement is mainly used in the main program and not in subroutines. That makes it seem like it's a runtime assignment before execution of the rest of the program.  As I understand it, it's equivalent to assignment except that it runs before everything else.  Am I wrong on that?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yeah it took me a long time to type them out.  I hope I didn't miscount!

Comment: @francescalus Also these data statments appear to never compile either when I have this many.  It fails after several hours of compilation (or at least it did using array assignments).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't know enough about the array of integers to make assumptions about it.  Surely they're not random, but I don't see a pattern.  But this is really beside the point as I'm really trying to figure out why how to initialize this at compile time.

Comment: They are compiled by incorporating the values into the data segment of the executable. If they were run-time assignments, there wouldn't be any crash.

Comment: The answer is: don't do it. Just read the values from a file. The way you are doing it now in C the Fortran code doesn't see it is a constant anyway.

Comment: I could explain more about explicit initialization, but I think that would distract from the much better advice that you really don't want to do that.

Comment: Yeah I get it, but just coming from c it's kind of irritating that this is a non issue in c.  I was trying to find an equivalent workaround, but I suppose that there isn't a better way than loading from a file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortran-C Interoperable variables must have external linkage.  As suggested by others in the comments, move the C declaration to file scope and lose the `static` specifier.

There is no need for an intermediate `C_PTR` - a Fortran array variable is directly interoperable with the appropriate C array.

Reducing the size of the array slightly:

```
/* C File scope */
const int f_init_g[3] = { 101, 102, 103 };

! Fortran
MODULE m
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_INT
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER(C_INT), BIND(C, NAME='f_init_g') :: f_init_g(3)
END MODULE m

PROGRAM p
  USE m
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRINT *, f_init_g(2)
END PROGRAM p
```

Note that the starting premise - that it is impossible to define or initialize such an array from within Fortran only - is false.  The rules around constant expressions in Fortran permit reference to existing named constants, including named constants that are arrays.  If you decide to persist with this madness, and assuming that the value of the initializer cannot be described by some sort of expression, consider:

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: first(10)  &
   = [ 3263,    322,     3261,    60,       32249,  &
       32244,   3229,    23408,   252407,   25326 ]
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: second(10)  &
   = [ 25805,   25723,   25562,   25787,    4549,  &
       32248,   32244,   32243,   253207,   21806]
...
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: f_init_g(1600000) = [ first, second, ... ]
```

You will probably need intermediate named constant arrays before the final array constructor.

In the immediate above, `f_init_g` is a named constant, which is very visible to the compiler, and more likely to result in the optimisations that you seek.

However, you may run into compiler complexity limits, that defeat this latter approach.

When `f_init_g` is a variable initialized by C, you are basically reliant on the inter-language and inter-procedural optimisation capabilities of your tool set - and if those capabilities even exist, I wouldn't expect much from them for this case.  I expect that you aren't going to lose much performance wise, beyond the one-off time for IO, if you read the value of the array in from a file at runtime.

Comment: Thanks!  This is the type of answer I was looking for.  I just needed to know how to do it in Fortran.  There isn't an easy expression that can initialize this array and knowing it at compile time will actually help me out quite a bit.  I appreciate the help.